# Why i can not update data into mysql when use function getimagesize php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Why i can not update data into mysql when use function `getimagesize` php ?

This is my code `test.php` for update data into mysql.

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
?>

<form class="form" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data">
<textarea id="editor" name="editor">
</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>


<?PHP
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $editor = $_POST['editor'];

    preg_match_all('/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i', $editor, $image_article);
    $og_image_video_length =  count($image_article[0]);

    for($i_og_image_video=0;$i_og_image_video<$og_image_video_length;$i_og_image_video++)
    {
        $og_image_video_temp = $image_article[1][$i_og_image_video];
        $og_image_video_dimension = getimagesize($og_image_video_temp);
    }

    $db_mysqli->query("Update test_1 Set xxx = '$editor' Where id = '170'");
}
?>
```

For test my code have to paste this data into `textarea`

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://scontent.fbkk5-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/25446441_1413986165396057_7730258373599423649_n.jpg?oh=7dd78be017547338429061b5868732a9&amp;oe=5AB769F6" alt=""><br></p><p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://scontent.fbkk5-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/25395840_1413986205396053_7023894077762247342_n.jpg?oh=355cfdc72a8be04e7a8faf320738780c&amp;oe=5AB4061B" alt=""><br></p><p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://scontent.fbkk5-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/25354046_1413986228729384_9088440758302530916_n.jpg?oh=4c4bff19766cc26c6bc44dc0ee80593f&amp;oe=5AC8683C" alt=""><br></p><p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://scontent.fbkk5-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/25399057_1413986272062713_4885847107829951044_n.jpg?oh=52d769a4812bf0cbf2d068095e5f7c8e&amp;oe=5AB875F1" alt=""><br></p><p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://scontent.fbkk5-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/24991265_1413986312062709_6468604703993578183_n.jpg?oh=96809eaceb433029db568b55f1aabc76&amp;oe=5ACD2A84" alt=""><br></p><p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://scontent.fbkk5-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/25443220_1413986365396037_3000883131483917887_n.jpg?oh=128427322f0167b631585d2876d40056&amp;oe=5AFD7103" alt=""><br></p><p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://scontent.fbkk5-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/25395804_1413986418729365_2494327754410292166_n.jpg?oh=50816bc486e3bbfcc5481fb843da6b62&amp;oe=5AB4771A" alt=""><br></p><p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://scontent.fbkk5-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/25396114_1413986455396028_7613670411230571813_n.jpg?oh=3435fa15c4b53e8ac393135b61aa3c4c&amp;oe=5AFE8856" alt=""><br></p><p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://scontent.fbkk5-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/25498256_1413986482062692_3071425741853380360_n.jpg?oh=09dad424b5b98fa53b322030370d83ab&amp;oe=5AF69C6A" alt=""><br></p><p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://scontent.fbkk5-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/25354096_1413986518729355_6808451190074179510_n.jpg?oh=d4d15fbbc0869aead0365f1145b69249&amp;oe=5AFA907A" alt=""><br></p>
```

When press button. It's will not update data into mysql.

But When i remove this code from `test.php`

```
        $og_image_video_dimension = getimagesize($og_image_video_temp);
```

It's will be update data into mysql success.

I want to know why i can not update data into mysql when use function `getimagesize` php ?

Comment: Make sure the links you pass to `getimagesize` is accessible

Comment: You need to check the value that is being returned from the getimagesize function and act appropriately. Secondly you need to ensure that "allow_url_fopen" is set in php.ini.